# What to do in this situation

Tags: salat, sunnah

If someone is not at his home and someone else's house and he has the time to pray 2 rakah because he has to go back to his house so what to do should he pray 2 rakah of fajr sunnah or farz (notice: there are chances that the sun will rise until he reaches home ) so what is the best thing to do

Answer (score 0):

If there is very short time, so that if you will pray 2 rakah sunnah then the time of fajr will be end, then you should and must pray 2 rakah fard, because sunnah is voluntary rakah prayed by prophet Muhammad (SAW). and fard is what is obligatory on a muslim.